# Tokenizing an array of string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, split, strtok

I'm new to programing and for the life of me I can't figure out this problem. I'm trying to create a function that tokenizes a string taking space as the delimiter and a pointer to the string and the number of tokens as the parameter. The function should return a char array with the tokenized string Ex. turning "( 2 + ( 5 - 3 ) )" into { "(", "2", "+", "(", "5", "-", "3", ")", ")"}. My code goes as follows:

```
char** get_tokens(char* str, int n_tokens)
{
  char *new;
  int i = 0;
  char ** new_arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * n_tokens);
  if(new_arr == NULL)
    return NULL;

  new = strtok(str, " ");
  while(new != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", new);
    new = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  char** p;

  return p;
}
```

The char** p line is just filler code for no compiling errors.

I believe I have used strtok() properly but the part I'm having troubles with is understanding the return type. I'm not not sure on how to utilize a char** return and have an array with the tokenized string for later use. If someone could help explain a pointer to a pointer return type and ways to help make my code do what I want, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `char **` can point to an array of `char *`, which is what you want to return.

In your loop, you want to assign the return value of `strtok` to elements of the array that `new_arr` points to.  You also want to allocate space for elements of size `sizeof(char *)`, not `sizeof(char)`:

```
  char ** new_arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n_tokens);
  if(new_arr == NULL)
    return NULL;

  new = strtok(str, " ");
  while(new != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", new);
    new_arr[i++] = new;
    new = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  return new_arr;
```

This works under the assumption that the value of `n_tokens` is correct.  If you don't know how many tokens, you can still do this by using `realloc` to expand the size of the array:

```
  char ** new_arr = malloc(sizeof(char *));
  if(new_arr == NULL)
    return NULL;

  new = strtok(str, " ");
  while(new != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", new);
    new_arr[i++] = new;
    new_arr = realloc(new_arr, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
    if (new_arr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    new = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  return new_arr;
```

Comment: @Soulo Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.